# Java BufferStrategy Flickering

Tags: java

I was watching a tutorial on using a BufferStrategy in Java and I wanted to test a very simple example. The issue is that it flickers intensely and it seems as if a piece of the starting oval stays on the screen. I know that the loop is a very bad practice but I just wanted to very simply test the BufferStrategy.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game extends JFrame {
    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    public Game() {
        setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        add(canvas);

        setVisible(true);

        canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
        BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();

        int x = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while(true) {
            i++;

            if(i == 10) {
                i = 0;
                x++;
            }

            bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
            Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(x, 200, 50, 100);
            g.dispose();
            bufferStrategy.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get flickering because you do not clear the screen after each frame.
Add this after you set your graphics object.

g.clearRect(0,0,width,height);

Plus you do not need to call super.paint() method either.